# How to add plus minus icon to accordion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, accordion

I have an accordion inside an AngularJS app, and I am using jQuery to expand and collapse it: everything is working fine but I need to put plus/minus toggling icons for the expand and collapse.

I have already written the jQuery part, but the problem is the icon is changing on expanding but not on collapsing.

Here is the code:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title 1',

      isOpen: true,
      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',

      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'
      ]
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',

    }
  ];
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parents").click(function() {
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
      $(".childs").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.childs {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <div class="parents"><i class="glyphicon-minus"></i> {{ group.title }}
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well you’ve only written half of the necessary logic, so what else did you expect? Have you at least _thought_ about what needs to happen in what order, to achieve this?

Comment: Just I need to interchange the icon in my jquery code..apart from that every thing is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is what is your actual _problem_ doing that? I mean, you are closing all children that are not the current one by sliding them up already … so what exactly is keeping you from now setting +/- exactly the other way around as you already do for the current item by that same logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check which class is active and add/remove respectively.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".parents").click(function() {

    if($(this).find("i").attr('class')=='glyphicon-plus'){
      $(this).find('i').addClass('glyphicon-minus');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
     }
     else{
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('glyphicon-minus');
      $(this).find('i').addClass('glyphicon-plus');
      }
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
      $(".childs").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
    });
  });

<body ng-app="app">
  <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <div class="parents"><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{ group.title }}
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine